# IronPython as Scripting language to C# WPF VS 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, ironpython

I'm having some trouble that I hope you can help with! I've being trying to update this grid.Width parameter in a while loop, in a sleep(500) step. But, when I hit run script on my program, the entire GUI stops. I already tried running the script on a different Thread and using BackgroundWorker, but still both ways they block my application GUI until the script is finished. Could you take a look in the following code please?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string script;
    ScriptEngine engine;
    ScriptScope scope;
    Thread threadScript;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        scope = engine.CreateScope();
        string variableName = "isto";
        object gridMier = gridScript;
        scope.SetVariable(variableName, gridMier);
    }

    public void rodarScript()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                //PARTE PARA ADICIONAR BIBLIOTECAS BASICAS PARA DESENVOLVIMENTO COM OS SCRIPTS
                script = @"#Reference the WPF assemblies
import clr
clr.AddReferenceByName(""PresentationFramework, Version = 3.0.0.0, Culture =       neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35"")
clr.AddReferenceByName(""PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"")
import System.Windows
def getMyObject():
    return isto

objeto = getMyObject()

#Atalhos de referencias para adicionar
Thickness = System.Windows.Thickness
from System.Threading.Thread import Sleep
Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug";

                script = script + "\n" + textBoxScript.Text;
                var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
                //var compiled = source.Compile();
                //var result = compiled.Execute(scope);
                source.Execute(scope);
            }
            catch (Exception qualquerExcecaoEncontrada)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(qualquerExcecaoEncontrada.ToString(), "Scripting Test do Mier", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }));
    }

    private void buttonScript_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        threadScript = new Thread(rodarScript);
        threadScript.Start();
    }
}
}
```

example of the code in IronPython (textBoxScript.Text)

```
for num in range(1,100):
    objeto.Width = objeto.Width + 1
    Sleep(500)
```

This simple code, running on a Thread, blocks my entire GUI for 50 seconds.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Lucas.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `threadScript` is never used.  You immediately `Dispatcher.Invoke` back to the UI thread.

Comment: Sorry Mitch quite didn't understand that. threadScript is used when I click on this Button i have in the Application. buttonScript_Click starts it.

Comment: You start it, but immediately go back to the UI thread.  You never do any work from `threadScript`.  If that doesn't make sense, you should probably try and better understand what `Dispatcher.Invoke` does: it runs an arbitrary method on the UI thread, and waits for the result.  So, all of the code you have in `rodarScript` is running on the UI thread, not on `threadScript`.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying. Actually, the IronPython script doesn't lock my GUI when I take off this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {}))); The problem is that I kinda need it, otherwise I will get this error that I can't access gridScript, because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @LucasMeyer try to use `BeginInvoke` and see what happens.

Comment: I'm having to use this.Dispatcher.Invoke in >>script = script + "\n" + textBoxScript.Text<<, there it doesn't block my UI, but I also need it in  >>source.Execute(scope)<<, to be able to edit the Width of gridScript. I tried using this.Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in the source.Execute(scope), but there it still blocks my UI (I took the Dispatcher.Invoke off the entire try and catch sentence). I'm thinking that I probably need a way of just running the this.Dispatcher.Invoke inside my IronPython script, when I change the Width of the grid, so it doesn't crash my UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a seperate thread and then putting the complete content in `Dispatcher.Invoke` does not sence. Because you are then again sync with the ui thread (the howle time). You should only invoke those things, which needs to be (UI access). First remove that from `rodarScript` and only use it for `script = script + "\n" + textBoxScript.Text;`:

```
    public void rodarScript()
    {
        try
        {
            //PARTE PARA ADICIONAR BIBLIOTECAS BASICAS PARA DESENVOLVIMENTO COM OS SCRIPTS
            script = @"#...";

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                script = script + "\n" + textBoxScript.Text;
            }));

            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
            //var compiled = source.Compile();
            //var result = compiled.Execute(scope);
            source.Execute(scope);
        }
        catch (Exception qualquerExcecaoEncontrada)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(qualquerExcecaoEncontrada.ToString(), "Scripting Test do Mier", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

(Removed IP-Code).

Then add some simple method, which accepts an instance of `PythonFunction` and add it as a variable, like this:

```
public void ExecuteInUI(object obj)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        var op = engine.CreateOperations(scope);
        op.Invoke(obj);
    }));
}
```

Add as variable:

```
scope.SetVariable("execute_in_ui", new Action<object>(ExecuteInUI));
```

Then you have to chagne your Python code a little bit, because you only want to use BeginInvoke, when you access the ui:

```
def inc_width():
    objeto.Width = objeto.Width + 1

for num in range(1,100):
    execute_in_ui(inc_width)
    Sleep(500)
```

So we are passing the function information of `inc_width` to c# and execute it from there in `ExecuteInUI`. Then complete code will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace AsyncIronPython
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string script;
        ScriptEngine engine;
        ScriptScope scope;
        Thread threadScript;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            scope = engine.CreateScope();
            string variableName = "isto";
            object gridMier = gridScript;
            scope.SetVariable(variableName, gridMier);
            scope.SetVariable("execute_in_ui", new Action<object>(ExecuteInUI));
        }

        public void ExecuteInUI(object obj)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                var op = engine.CreateOperations(scope);
                op.Invoke(obj);
            }));
        }

        public void rodarScript()
        {
            try
            {
                //PARTE PARA ADICIONAR BIBLIOTECAS BASICAS PARA DESENVOLVIMENTO COM OS SCRIPTS
                script = @"#Reference the WPF assemblies
import clr
clr.AddReferenceByName(""PresentationFramework, Version = 3.0.0.0, Culture =       neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35"")
clr.AddReferenceByName(""PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"")
import System.Windows
def getMyObject():
    return isto

objeto = getMyObject()

#Atalhos de referencias para adicionar
Thickness = System.Windows.Thickness
from System.Threading.Thread import Sleep
Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug";

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    script = script + "\n" + textBoxScript.Text;
                }));

                var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
                //var compiled = source.Compile();
                //var result = compiled.Execute(scope);
                source.Execute(scope);
            }
            catch (Exception qualquerExcecaoEncontrada)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(qualquerExcecaoEncontrada.ToString(), "Scripting Test do Mier", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }

        private void buttonScript_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            threadScript = new Thread(rodarScript);
            threadScript.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncIronPython.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AsyncIronPython"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="gridScript">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxScript" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonScript" Click="buttonScript_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Execute" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @BengEg and people, that was exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to be able to create animations in textBoxes, Grids, User Controls in general, using IronPython script inside C# WPF. So, I was having trouble to find a way of doing so, since the User Controls are being used by another threads in my program. So, here is the final "Testing Scripting code".

CSharp

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using IronPython.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Scripting;
    using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

    namespace AsyncIronPython
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            string script;
            ScriptEngine engine;
            ScriptScope scope;
            Thread threadScript;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                scope = engine.CreateScope();
                scope.SetVariable("objetoEditavel", gridScript);
                scope.SetVariable("execute_in_ui", new Action<object>(ExecuteInUI));
            }

            public void ExecuteInUI(object obj)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    var op = engine.CreateOperations(scope);
                    op.Invoke(obj);
                }));
            }

            public void rodarScript()
            {
                try
                {
                    //PARTE PARA ADICIONAR BIBLIOTECAS BASICAS PARA DESENVOLVIMENTO COM OS SCRIPTS
                    script = @"#Reference the WPF assemblies
    import clr
    clr.AddReferenceByName(""PresentationFramework, Version = 3.0.0.0, Culture =       neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35"")
    clr.AddReferenceByName(""PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"")
    import System.Windows
    def getMyObject():
        return objetoEditavel

    objeto = getMyObject()

    #Atalhos de referencias para adicionar
    Thickness = System.Windows.Thickness
    from System.Threading.Thread import Sleep
    Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug";

                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>{script = script + "\n" + textBoxScript.Text;}));

                    var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
                    source.Execute(scope);
                }
                catch (Exception qualquerExcecaoEncontrada)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(qualquerExcecaoEncontrada.ToString(), "Scripting Test do Mier", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
            }

            private void buttonScript_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                threadScript = new Thread(rodarScript);
                threadScript.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="AsyncIronPython.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AsyncIronPython"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxScript" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="261,3,3,3" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Background="#FFFFD6D6" />
            <Button x:Name="buttonScript" Click="buttonScript_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Execute" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" />
            <Grid x:Name="gridScript" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Background="Black"/>

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

IronPython Script inside gridScript (will basically create an animation of this black box grid to grow in a interval of 50 miliseconds.

```
    def inc_width():
        objeto.Width = objeto.Width + 1

    for num in range(1,100):
        execute_in_ui(inc_width)
        Sleep(50)
```